# Qt 5.5 and Visual Studio C++ 2015 Linker problems

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015

I have a static library compiled with Visual C++ 2015 compiler and I would like to use it in a Qt project. Everything is set in the Qt project's .pro file, but the MinGW compiler can not find the function definitions in the library. It's okay, because it was built with another compiler. The question is how can I use the lib in my Qt project? VS C++ 2015 is not in the compatibility list of Qt 5.5, but I need to use its compiler to make my project run.

Comment: You'll need to build Qt from sources yourself with VS2015  or wait for Qt 5.6 - likely they will add binaries for VS2015 in that version.

Comment: Nobody uploded a VS2015 version? :( It would be great if I could just download it. Thank for the answer btw.